# How do I create a Java delay class?

Tags: java, class, delay

I have this code:

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

How do I put it in it's own class file so I can reference all that code just at something like "Wait();" within the main class?

Comment: Please explain your real problem. Using something like this in production is not appropriate.

Comment: That ^ and you should read a basic Java tutorial on how to write classes and methods.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza great, but why do you even refer to production?

Comment: Basically I want to be able to use a delay in a java class more than once, but I don't want to have to use the same code over and over.

Comment: That's not your real problem. Why would you want to use a delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make class

```
public class WaitTools {
    public static void Wait() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

And then use java static imports (if you want)

```
import static YOURPACKAGE.WaitTools.Wait;
```

and you should directly use `Wait();`

or classical way

```
import YOURPACKAGE.WaitTools;
```

and calling it `WaitTools.Wait();`

Comment: What would my package name be? The folder is called BasicBox would it be that?

Comment: It's package, where your class is located.

Comment: Does that mean: Import static Basicbox.WaitTools? as that doesn't work.

Comment: So, when you create class in eclipse it will be in some package. Look at package browser (located in left). Or if you generate it using eclipse, it automatically adds package YOURPACKAGE; into your class.
Try coppy that